# How to make my collapsingToolbar work correctly?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have implemented this horizontal scroll view inside my collapsing toolbar (because I want users to horizontally scroll through images). And my collapsing toolbar isnt collapsing correctly (there's this random space (in color orange) after it has collapsed. I was hoping you guys can look at my xml and tell me what im doing wrong here.

Here we have it not collapsed.
[image]

**Here we have it collapsed (and we have this orange space). Also how do i put a margin from my horizontal scroll view and the toolbar so that it would work on all devices?**

[image]

Here is my xml code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardInfo_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/cardInfo_collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">
            <include
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_layout_edit_card"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
            </include>
            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/cardInfo_HSV_LL">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/image_kyoto"
                        android:id="@+id/cardInfo_imageView"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and my toolbar layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_edit_card_ID"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:theme="@style/Frontier2017_2"
    android:background="@color/orange_test"
    android:elevation="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_textview"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Edit"
        android:background="@color/orange_test"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Set _android:fitsSystemWindows="true"_ for _CoordinateLayout_

Comment: @Piyush that didnt solve the problem. The image or horizontal scrollview isnt fitting correctly under the toolbar

Comment: I am not sure of using scrollview. Note CollapsingToolbarLayout extends FrameLayout so does ScrollView. Why not use a viewPager instead?

Comment: And using view pager will look something like https://youtu.be/Tg28gXLis8U

Comment: Actually i figured out what was wrong. AppBarLayout needed to have `        android:layout_height="wrap_content"` instead a specified height as i did above.